# How to set editable false in vaadin time picker

Tags: vaadin

In vaadin time picker we can type, now i **want to set editable false**. so that user can't type.
here,only can select time from the list.. has any method for set editable false in **vaadin time picker**

there are several method for vaadin time picker, i can see set read only method and other's method ,not find set editable false.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official Java API for that at the moment, or even attribute in the component, but you can achieve the goal by disabling the input element of the combobox like this:

```
timePicker.getElement().executeJs("this.inputElement.setAttribute('disabled', true)");
```

Comment: timePicker= new TimePicker();  timePicker.getElement().executeJavaScript("this.inputElement.setAttribute('disabled', true)");
-- not working

Comment: I am using vaadin 13.

Comment: As I know vaadin 13 version not supported -> migrate to 14.x version

Comment: I tested my solution with Vaadin 24. In Vaadin 14 the internal DOM may be different, so the JavaScript could be different.

Comment: Any suggestion for vaaadin 13?? @Tatu Llund